# AbpRemoteCallException: An internal error occurred during your request

Tags: c#, .net, abp

AbpRemoteCallException: An internal error occurred during your request!

```
Volo.Abp.Http.Client.ClientProxying.ClientProxyBase<TService>.ThrowExceptionForResponseAsync(HttpResponseMessage response)
Volo.Abp.Http.Client.ClientProxying.ClientProxyBase<TService>.RequestAsync(ClientProxyRequestContext requestContext)
Volo.Abp.Http.Client.ClientProxying.ClientProxyBase<TService>.RequestAsync<T>(ClientProxyRequestContext requestContext)
Volo.Abp.Http.Client.ClientProxying.ClientProxyBase<TService>.RequestAsync<T>(string methodName, ClientProxyRequestTypeValue arguments)
Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationConfigurations.ClientProxies.AbpApplicationConfigurationClientProxy.GetAsync(ApplicationConfigurationRequestOptions options)
Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.Client.MvcCachedApplicationConfigurationClient.GetRemoteConfigurationAsync()
Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.Client.MvcCachedApplicationConfigurationClient.<GetAsync>b__19_0()
Volo.Abp.Caching.DistributedCache<TCacheItem, TCacheKey>.GetOrAddAsync(TCacheKey key, Func<Task<TCacheItem>> factory, Func<DistributedCacheEntryOptions> optionsFactory, Nullable<bool> hideErrors, bool considerUow, CancellationToken token)
Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.Client.MvcCachedApplicationConfigurationClient.GetAsync()
Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.Client.RemoteLanguageProvider.GetLanguagesAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.RequestLocalization.DefaultAbpRequestLocalizationOptionsProvider.GetLocalizationOptionsAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.RequestLocalization.AbpRequestLocalizationMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions+InterfaceMiddlewareBinder+<>c__DisplayClass2_0+<<CreateMiddleware>b__0>d.MoveNext()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

can anyone tell me why im getting this error message?

i encountered this after deleting unnecessary localization files ,

this is LeptonX project and deleted the `<locale>.json` files for from the src and demo folder.

Comment: What was your original code?

Comment: @OwJi i had several localization .json files. "en.json , it.json , ....". 
they were like 15 of them , i deleted all except 2 of them.

after cleaning and rebuilding the project again , i encountered this error

Comment: did you delete the entries in the [AbpLanguages] table ?